# How do you make a transparent view that changes color

Tags: swift

I want to make an app that puts a colored transparent layer over an image, so that you can see the image just like looking with your eyes with a colored transparent sheet in front of your face.
What should I start off with??

Comment: Just put a `UIView` over the image, set background color and alpha for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is code version.

You need to create an outlet for your image in your view controller (right click on the image from storyboard to view controller swift file - select Outlet and name it imageHome). You will see the following IBOutlet is created:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageHome: UIImageView!
```

And use the following code in the view controller to see if it helps to start:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Create a view programmatically by using the image's frame
    let transparentVC = UIView.init(frame: self.imageHome.frame)

    // Set its background color with alpha value for transparency
    transparentVC.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 255 / 255, green: 0 / 255, blue: 0 / 255, alpha: 0.4)

    // Add this new view to your image as subview, so it will be top view on the actual image
    self.imageHome.addSubview(transparentVC)
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to hear it helps.